# How to enable PyCharm code inspection for packages

Tags: python, pycharm

I recently created a Python package which I use in most of my projects so I moved it to my user-site directory (python -m site --user-site). Everything works perfectly now except for the fact that PyCharm has disabled code inspection for it.

Is there any way for me to enable code inspection without moving the project back to a different directory?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was because I didn't have an interpreter set for my project (and not that it was placed in a site-packages directory). I assumed that it did due to the fact that PyCharm didn't have it's usual "no interpreter configured for this project" alert. Finally figured it out when I went poking in the settings.